# Is there a Go equivalent of `ToString()` that `fmt.Print` will use?

Tags: go

I've looked in the documentation and couldn't find this info.
Given a struct, is it possible to implement a method (say, `func (k Koala) String() string`) that will automatically be used by the `fmt.Print` family when printing a struct?
Maybe there's an interface somewhere, but I didn't find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's called [`fmt.Stringer()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer)

> Stringer is implemented by any value that has a String method, which defines the “native” format for that value. The String method is used to print values passed as an operand to any format that accepts a string or to an unformatted printer such as Print.
>
> ```
> type Stringer interface {
>     String() string
> }
> ```

The `*print*` functions don't accept a `Stringer()` interface themselves because `fmt.Println("foo")` and `fmt.Println(someStringer)` are equally valid. I recommend you go through the [`print.go` source code](https://golang.org/src/fmt/print.go) to see *exactly* how this works, but in brief the `*print*` functions:

- accept an `interface{}`;
- check if it's a built-in type (e.g. `string`, `int`, etc.) and format it accordingly if it is;
- check if the type has a `.String()` method and use that if it exists.

The precise logic is a bit more involved. As mentioned, I encourage you to go through the source code yourself. It's all just plain readable Go.